# Was this an appropriate edit?

Tags: discussion, edits

I applied a fairly minor edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37125323/827263). I made a small change to the title to clear up what I thought was a potential ambiguity, and changed the markup for the error messages from blockquote to code sample. (I've made similar edits before.)

My initial edit was #7 in the edit history.

Another user objected to my edit, saying that I had made only "cosmetic changes", and rolled back my changes. (I'm not interested in getting into an edit war.)

I'm interested in other opinions on this. Was my original edit appropriate?

Comment: Marking terminal output as a code block was correct.  Adding "The script:" before what is obviously the script was not.  It's not worth starting an edit war over though.

Comment: @davidism: Without "The script:", the error messages and the code appeared as a single code block. There was probably a more elegant way to do that.

Comment: `<!-- break -->` or any comment will split blocks.

Comment: @davidism: Yes, that should work. On the other hand, I'm not convinced that the "The script:" marker is such a bad idea. No biggie either way IMHO.

Comment: @KeithThompson I think it should be obvious to anyone that it is the code. It's just noise. But I do think that the question title is a little ambiguous now.

Comment: Seemed good to me.

Comment: The question in question was deleted in 2016.